# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\frac { f(-x){ x }^{ 2 } }{ \left\{ \frac { 1-\cos(x) }{ [f(x)] } \right\} } $?

Tags: limits

Let $f(x)$ be a real valued continuous function, except at $x=0$. $f'(x)<0$ for negative real values of $x$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all positive real values of $x$.

Let $\lim_{x\to0^{+}} f(x)=2$,$\lim_{x\to0^{-}} f(x)=3$ and $f(0)=4$.

Then how to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0^{-}}\dfrac { f(-x){ x }^{ 2 } }{ \left\{ \frac { 1-\cos(x) }{ [f(x)] }  \right\}  } $?
where $[\cdot]$ denotes greatest integer function, and $\{\cdot\}$ denotes fraction part function.

Comment: I edited your question with my best effort. However, I am confusing why you left a big space in between $\cos$ and $x$. Does it have any special meaning?

Comment: No no...my mobile browser is a bit faulty that's why.There should be no space there. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Well you should start by simplifying what you want based on the conditions. Since the limit is $x \to 0$ from the negative side, $f(-x)$ is completely determined by what $f$ is like on positive reals so what does the numerator tend to? Likewise you can do the denominator in the same way. Note that limits and floor/ceil functions cannot be interchanged in general, so you need to be careful.